# Protect VPS,WHM,cPanel

Tags: cpanel, panel, whm, virtuozzo

Please guys help me, I want prevent my old developer from access to my VPS,WHM and cPanel what I should do. I don't want to lose my work.

I saw there is password for Virtuozzo Power Panel, WHM and cPanel there is my thing i need to change it.

like how I know if he have SSH access or not. or any recovery can he recover the passwords

Answer (score 0):

If you have given Password, SSH and FTP access to your developer you can consider doing the following:

1. Change your WHM's root password
2. Change all of your cPanel accounts' passwords (or those that your
   developer had access to, if he had access to the whole WHM - you
   might want to change all passwords)
3. Make sure there aren't any authorized SSH keys for the root user.
   This can be seen through **WHM's interface**, docs [here](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/68Docs/Manage+root%27s+SSH+Keys)
4. Make sure there aren't any authized SSH keys for any cPanel user as
   well. This can be done through each cPanel account's **SSH Access**
   tool
5. Check all cPanel accounts for unauthorized FTP accounts.
6. You can also take a look at the cron jobs that are running as well.
7. Ultimatively you should also consider looking for any backdoors that
   might be present in the scripts that your developer was working on.

Comment: Thanks you for answer, I have checked all points from 1 to 6. But for point 7, I have searched for any curl, website link and send email script, but the code is big. what is the worse case can do it with the back door?

Comment: Have full control over your cPanel account

Comment: He can retrieve cPanel password from script or change database password??

Comment: He can gain complete SSH access using PHP, having almost full control over the cPanel account